# Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at path $ - Retrofit2 with RxJava handling JSONArray response

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, rx-java, moshi

I was able to make it work with a JSON object response but when I tried a JSON Array response I am having an error

`Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at path $`

Lets say I am using this JSON Array

```
[
  {
    "id": 272846,
    "date": "2021-04-04T15:26:48",
    "link": "https://sample.com/crypto-that-surged-by-1250-in-2021-teams-up-with-cardano/",
    "title": {
      "rendered": "sample"
    },
    "content": {
      "rendered": "sample",
      "protected": false
    },
    "author": 52,
    "jetpack_featured_media_url": "https://sample.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/Untitled-design-3-1.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": 272841,
    "date": "2021-04-04T11:03:54",
    "link": "https://sample.com/global-financial-services-company-btig-is-bullish-on-bitcoin-and-microstrategy/",
    "title": {
      "rendered": "sample"
    },
    "content": {
      "rendered": "sample",
      "protected": false
    },
    "author": 52,
    "jetpack_featured_media_url": "https://sample.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/3-feb-2021-05-1024x576-1.jpg"
  }
]
```

The generated Kotlin (Codegen) class using this [plugin](https://github.com/wuseal/JsonToKotlinClass)

```
class NewsItemModels : ArrayList<NewsItemModel>()
```

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class NewsItemModel(
    @Json(name = "author")
    val author: Int,
    @Json(name = "content")
    val content: Content,
    @Json(name = "date")
    val date: String,
    @Json(name = "id")
    val id: Int,
    @Json(name = "jetpack_featured_media_url")
    val jetpackFeaturedMediaUrl: String,
    @Json(name = "link")
    val link: String,
    @Json(name = "title")
    val title: Title
)
```

With a service like this

```
 @GET("posts")
    fun getNewsItems(
        @Query("_fields") key: String,
        @Query("per_page") part: String,
        @Query("categories") category: String
    ):
            Observable<NewsItemModels>
```

Service interface

```
companion object {

        fun create(baseUrl: String): EndpointServices {

            val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .addCallAdapterFactory(
                    RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create()
                )
                .addConverterFactory(
                    MoshiConverterFactory.create()
                )
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .build()

            return retrofit.create(EndpointServices::class.java)

        }

    }
```

Fetching

```
fetch.getNewsItems(
            "author,id,title,content,date,link,jetpack_featured_media_url",
            "30",
            categoryId
        ) //Get the first channel id
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(
                { result ->
                    Log.wtf("WTF", "$result")
                    swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing = false
                },
                { error ->
                    Log.wtf("WTF", "${error.message}")
                    swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing = false
                }
            )
```

I was able to work with JSON Object response but not with JSONArray as much as possible I want only one Retrofit.Builder code. What is the missing part here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either do:

```
    @GET("posts")
    fun getNewsItems(
        @Query("_fields") key: String,
        @Query("per_page") part: String,
        @Query("categories") category: String
    ): Observable<List<NewsItemModel>>
```

or update your definition of `NewsItemModels` to:

```
typealias NewsItemModels = List<NewsItemModel>
```

The error message:

> Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at path $

comes from Gson, and it's telling you that based on the way you defined the `getNewsItems` it's expecting an object (you defined `NewsItemModels` as a class) but it's getting an array.

In your example JSON the received payload it's an array so you need to update the return type to either inline the `List` or use a `typealias`.

Comment: I tried `Observable<List<NewsItemModel>>` I just get another error will try typealias instead, I am using Moshi not GSON.

Comment: Sorry, I guess Moshi and Gson have a similar error message. Both solutions I proposed are equivalent. Are you sure you get the same error message when updating the signature?

Comment: what error are you getting with `List<NewsItemModel>`?

Comment: This is weird I tried this before many times and failed or maybe I pass a different type. Anyway it works now with just `Observable<List<NewsItemModel>>` so I am deleting now the class `NewsItemModels`. However when I tried `Observable<ArrayList<NewsItemModel>>` it gives an error
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create converter for java.util.ArrayList<com.app.app.NewsItemModel>` why is that?

Comment: Maybe `ArrayList` is not one of the built-in adapters: https://github.com/square/moshi#built-in-type-adapters and `List` is definetly there

Comment: Great! Now I understand what are the reason. Thank you so much will mark this as an answer. I was really trying to avoid making any unnecessary custom adapter.

Comment: ArrayList imeplements MutableList and MutableList itself implements List so I wonder why ArrayList will not work.